# Change style for a single .bib-entry

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have an entry in bibliography and I want to change it's style.
But only this one, so I don't want to change every other styles.
Here is how it looks like:
[image]
But I want it to be:
[Wei24]  Eric W. Weisstein, Proth numbers, Entry A080075 in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, https://oeis.org/A080075

So: No quotation marks, add "Entry..." and no colon after >>In:<<.
How can I do that? Here is my file:

```
@article{oeis080075,
    author={Eric W. Weisstein},
    title={Proth numbers},
    year={2024},
    url={https://oeis.org/A080075},
    urldate = {2024-03-19},
    journal={The on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences},
}
```

Comment: If you employ `biblatex`, please provide information about the options with which you load that package.

Comment: What happens if you change the entry type from `@article` to `@misc` and the field `journal={The on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences},` to `howpublished={Entry A080075 in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences},`?

Comment: @Mico Yes I use biblatex. But I am absolutely not familiar with it. What option do you need?

Comment: All options. E.g., `style=alphabetic`?

Comment: @Mico I only have this n my code:
```
\addbibresource{quellen.bib} % The filename of the bibliograph
\makeindex
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
 andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}
```

Comment: Do you maybe use a template file (which you could have obtained from who knows where...) that loads the `biblatex` package automatically?

Comment: @Mico I guess not. I use Texstudio and just clicked "Biblatex". It works as it should for my purpose.

Comment: The `alphabetic` or `alpha` style is *not* the default style. If your document generates `alpha`-style citation call-outs, there has to be an instruction somewhere in the document that specifies this particular style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you (a) change the entry type from `@article` to `@misc` and (b) change

```
journal={The on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences},
```

to

```
howpublished={Entry A080075 in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences},
```

A general remark: The `@article` entry type should only be used for pieces published in scholarly journals. The "The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences" would not appear to fall into this category.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{oeis080075,
    author={Eric W. Weisstein},
    title={Proth numbers},
    year={2024},
    url={https://oeis.org/A080075},
    urldate = {2024-03-19},
    howpublished={Entry A080075 in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. In addition I set the date in brackets and it worked. Thank you Sir!

Comment: @Lereu - You're most welcome.